# How to get an file path in Java? I want to take that path in some string variable and use it further for some XML transformations

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I dont want to take the path using command line arguments.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String xmlPath, xsltPath;

        System.out.println("Enter the path of XML file");
        xmlPath = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the path of XSLT file");
        xsltPath = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Use swing's Filechooser to select your file.

Comment: I want to replace the above command line argument code by some GUI component. Please suggest with some examples of JFileChooser etc

Comment: Shriram plz post the example code

Comment: *"Please suggest with some examples of JFileChooser.."*  They are found in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).  SO is not a code factory, BTW.

Comment: `post the example code` ---> not why, to read Oracle tutorial how to use filechooser for working code example

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for example code that is found in [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame {
  public MainClass() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a file");
    this.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
    fileChooser.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new MainClass();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to extend frame, GUIs should be created on the EDT, a file chooser should not be added to the content pane of a frame, and if it is, there is no point in calling `setVisible(true)`..  We don't need more (poor) code to describe what is well described in the tutorial.  -1

Comment: i haven't pasted the complete code. Just an example to show how JFilechooser is ..

Comment: Also, your example code does not work.  If I could add another -1, I would.

Comment: how to get the absolute path of the file????
how can I use JFileChoser to get the file's complete path in a string variable?

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below link, it will be useful to you...

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/

```
File file = File("C:\\abcfolder\\textfile.txt");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: ..That would not compile.

Comment: This is not my requirement, I want to make the code portable, I just want a GUI that would appear when I run my application.
From that GUI, I want to take the file location into a String variable.